# Can't access fresh generated temp directory in bash script on macOS

Tags: bash, macos

I'm enhancing my .bash_profile with this script. It extracts an .ipa and shows me the provisioning profile information. The .ipa file gets extracted to a temporary directory.

```
function prov() {
    myTmpDir=`mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'myTmpDir'`
    unzip -q "$1" -d "${myTmpDir}";
    pathToFile="${myTmpDir}/Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision"
    security cms -D -i "${pathToFile}"
}
```

The problem is that `security cms` can't access the extracted files in the script:

```
mles-MacBook-Pro:2015 mles$ prov gfhZH_v4.7.0_20161222_1544.ipa 
security: unable to open "/var/folders/vc/rmwcd9014fx1__syr239k1740000gn/T/tmp.CrAJbnwj/Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision" for reading: No such file or directory
```

However accesing it by hand works:

```
mles-MacBook-Pro:2015 mles$ ls /var/folders/vc/rmwcd9014fx1__syr239k1740000gn/T/tmp.CrAJbnwj/Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
/var/folders/vc/rmwcd9014fx1__syr239k1740000gn/T/tmp.CrAJbnwj/Payload/fsg4zh.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

Running `security cms -D -i` by hand also works

```
mles-MacBook-Pro:2015 mles$ security cms -D -i /var/folders/vc/rmwcd9014fx1__syr239k1740000gn/T/tmp.CrAJbnwj/Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
...
```

Why is this not possible in the shell script?

Comment: Putting the variable in quotes prevents expanding the `*` wildcard. Why are you using that in the first place?

Comment: Ah ok. I don't know the name of the .app folder in advance. However there is only one .app folder so I need to find a way to resolve the wildcard first.

Comment: Removing the quotes works. They can be removed as I will definitely not have any spaces in that path. Convert your comment to an answer and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards aren't expanded when a variable is quoted. Since you want `*.app` to be expanded, you have to omit the quotes:

```
security cms -D -i ${pathToFile}
```

This will work as long as `$pathToFile` doesn't contain any spaces.

If that's a possibility, you'll need to split up the variable, so the wildcard is outside the quotes.

```
security cms -D -i "${myTmpDir}/Payload/"*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```